# How to embed the right url to custom font in HTML string

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms, url

How to embed the right url to custom font in my HTML string.

I do the following:

```
   string exeFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
   string path4 = Path.Combine(Regex.Escape(exeDir), "\\..\\\\..\\\\CSS\\\\majalla.ttf");
   string arabicFont = @"@font-face {
                      font-family: 'sakkal_majallaregular';
                      src: url(" + "'" + path4 + "'" + @"), url('majalla-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('majalla-webfont.woff') format('woff');}";
```

This doesn't work(doesn't take effect). After debugging `path4 =`

`C:\\Users\\AA\\Desktop\\PrintingStatement\\PrintingStatement\\bin\\Debug\\..\\..\\CSS\\majalla.ttf`

When I try the constant absolute url like this:

```
url('C:\\Users\\AA\\Desktop\\PrintingStatement\\PrintingStatement\\CSS\\majalla.ttf')
```

It works fine. How to convert my url to the previous one in production environment.

**MY Updated HTML Method**

```
   protected string StyleStatementDoc(SingleStatement statementToPrint)
        {
            string path1 = "CSS/StatementVerifacation.css";
            string path2 = "CSS/Statement.css";
            string path3 = "CSS/print.min.css";
            string path4 = "CSS/majalla.ttf"; 

            string arabicFont = @"@font-face {
                                            font-family: 'sakkal_majallaregular';
                                            src: url(" + "'" + path4 + "'" + @"), url('majalla-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('majalla-webfont.woff') format('woff');
                                           }";
            string htmlData = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                                <html>
                                <head>
                                    <title>Statement</title>
                                     <style>" + arabicFont + @"


                                            body {
                                            font-size: 20px;
                                            background-color: White;
                                            color: Black;
                                            font-family:'sakkal_majallaregular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                            text-align:right;
                                            direction:rtl;

                                             }
                                           p {
                                              line-height: 32px;   /* within paragraph */
                                              margin-bottom: 30px; /* between paragraphs */
                                              }
                                    </style>
                                    <link href = '" + path1 + "'" + " rel='stylesheet' />" + @"

                                   <link href = '" + path3 + "'" + " rel='stylesheet' />" + @"

                                        </head>
                                <body>
                                    <div class='my' id='editor1'>" + statementToPrint.StatementBeforePrint + @"

                                    </div>
                                </body>
                                </html>
                                ";

           // htmlData = htmlData.Replace(@"<head>", $@"<head><base href=""{new Uri(Application.StartupPath)}/""/>");
            return htmlData;
        }
       System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        protected void Print(string htmlData)
        {

            webBrowser.SetHtmlContent(htmlData, $@"{new Uri(Application.StartupPath)}/");

            webBrowser.Print();
        }
```

---

**My project structure:**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your browser's dev console to see what request is actually made and what the response is? Hit F12 in your browser.

Comment: @itsme86 the url in run time ``C:\\Users\\AA\\Desktop\\PrintingStatement\\PrintingStatement\\bin\\Debug\\..\\..\\CSS\\majalla.ttf``

Comment: If the font path has nothing to do with the directory the exe is in, why are you using that folder to build the URL? What part of that path are you trying to capture? The user's home directory?

Comment: @itsme86 This's windows form application, so I consider how should the paths be when i install it for the user(production env).

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Where is the html? where is the css? Where the font file is located?

Comment: @RezaAghaei the font file is in Css folder in my winform project. The html is in db as string. When i write the url abs ad const it works as expected but when i use the ‘exeFile’ var to access it, it doesn’t work

Comment: Try to create a simple html file, a simple css and put a font file close to them, all in the same folder. Then after being able to show the html file, css and the font correctly, then you will now the relative url which you need.

Comment: @RezaAghaei `url('CSS//majalla.ttf')` works in the simple html file but doesn't work in my winform project which has folder named `CSS` has the same font !

Comment: You need to copy the HTML file to filesystem. In the correct location.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I use `webBrowser.Document.Write(htmlData.ToString()); webBrowser.Print();` to print it directly without dialogs so I don't want to save the file to filesystem!

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with silent printing (having files on file-system will not prevent silent printing). Just put all the files in a temp directory on file system and everything will work fine.

Comment: @RezaAghaei may be I can't clarify my case as I have to, but for security issues I don't want to put such files on filesystem, I want to print them directly from DB with the embedded fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve relative addresses you have the following options:

1. Using a placeholder in html and replace it with bin folder address. (Works for everything but fonts)
2. Injection `<base>` tag in head. (Works for everything but fonts)
3. Implementing `IMoniker` to set base url for document. (Works for everything as well as fonts) I've implemented an extension method for `WebBrowser1.SetHtmlContent(html, url)`

**Example**

Assuming you have an html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Sample</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "MyFont";
            src: url('./Contents/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype');
        }

        body {
            background-image: url('./Contents/Image.jpeg');
            font-family: 'MyFont';
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Something
</body>
</html>
```

I assume you have `Contents` folder containing `Image.jpeg` and `MyFont.ttf` files in your project output directory. (If you have them in your project, them in your project, to copy them into output directory into the right folder structure, just in the properties window of those files in solution explorer, set `Copy to output directory` to `Copy Always`.)

**Solution 1 - use a placeholder in HTML file and replace it with bin path**

So instead of `./` use `$ROOT$/`, for example: `background-image:url('$ROOT$/Resources/Sample.jpeg');` Then when setting document text of the browser, replace it with start up path of the application:

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = yourHtmlContent.Replace("$ROOT$", 
    new Uri(Application.StartupPath).ToString());
```

**Solution 2 - Injectting html `<base>` tag**

Assuming you don't have any placeholder in the html content. Then it's enough to inject a `<base>` tag into `<head>` like this:

```
var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("HTMLPage1.html");
html = html.Replace(@"<head>", $@"<head><base href=""{new Uri(Application.StartupPath)}/""/>");
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

It means all the relative addresses will be resolved using `<base>` href attribute.

**Solution 3 - Implemeting `IMoniker`**

You can implement `IMoniker` interface and using `IWebBrowser2` from `SHDocVw` load the html content and set a base url for that. I used this method for relative address of `@font-face` as well as relative address for other stuff in html content and it worked well.

You find an Implementation which I shared in this post: [Set URL of custom HTML loaded in webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57380227/3110834) and easily use it like this:

```
webBrowser1.SetHtmlContent(html, 
    $@"{new Uri(Application.StartupPath)}/");
```