# Load HTML from IPersistMoniker to add base URL to relative links

Tags: c++builder, twebbrowser, moniker

I am attempting to load HTML from URL using `IPersistMoniker` to add relative URLs base path, for example `<img src="foo.jpg">` to load from `mypath/images/` (or any other path). From what I found the process is (based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167769/set-url-of-custom-html-loaded-in-webbrowser)):

1. implement `IMoniker` instance, in particular `GetDisplayName` (gives the URL for relative links) and `BindToStorage` (loads the content)
2. `QueryInterface` of the TWebBrowser Document for `IID_IPersistMoniker`
3. `CreateBindCtx` (not sure what this is for though)
4. use `Load` method of the `IPersistMoniker` to load HTML, passing the `IMoniker` instance from (1) and `CreateBindCtx` instance from (3)

`GetDisplayName` in my instance does get called, but the `BindToStorage` where I am supposed to pass the `IStream` to the actual HTML never gets called so the document always turns out blank, not loaded. The HRESULT is `E_INVALIDARG` for the call to `Load`. What have I missed?

IMoniker implementation (some things omitted):

```cpp
// Simple IMoniker implementation

class TMoniker : public IMoniker
    {
    private:    OleVariant              baseUrl;
                TMemoryStream*          memStream;
                LONG                    m_cRef;

    public:     TMoniker(const UnicodeString& fBaseUrl, const UnicodeString& fContent)
                    {
                    m_cRef        = 1;                                          // Set to 1 so that the AddRef() doesn't need to be called when initialized the first time
                    this->baseUrl = fBaseUrl;
                    memStream = new TMemoryStream;
                    memStream->LoadFromFile(fContent.SubString(8,fContent.Length()));
                    memStream->Position = 0;
                    }

                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                // IUnknown
                //--------------------------------------------------------------

                STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv);
                STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef();
                STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release();

                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                // IMoniker
                //--------------------------------------------------------------

                STDMETHODIMP GetDisplayName(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, LPOLESTR *ppszDisplayName)
                    {
                    Application->MessageBox(L"GetDisplayName", L"Info", MB_OK); // Check if method is called
                    // UPDATE - should be *ppszDisplayName = this->baseUrl;
                    ppszDisplayName = this->baseUrl;
                    return S_OK;
                    }

                STDMETHODIMP BindToStorage(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, REFIID riid, void **ppvObj)
                    {
                    Application->MessageBox(L"BindToStorage", L"Info", MB_OK); // Check if method is called

                    ppvObj = NULL;

                    if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IStream))
                        {
                        Application->MessageBox(L"IMoniker::BindToStorage", L"Info", MB_OK);
//                      DelphiInterface<IStream> sa(*(new TStreamAdapter(memStream.get(), soReference)));
//                      ppvObj = (IStream)sa;
                        }

                    return S_OK;
                    }

                STDMETHODIMP BindToObject(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, REFIID riidResult, void **ppvResult) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP Reduce(IBindCtx *pbc, DWORD dwReduceHowFar, IMoniker **ppmkToLeft, IMoniker **ppmkReduced) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP ComposeWith(IMoniker *pmkRight, BOOL fOnlyIfNotGeneric, IMoniker **ppmkComposite) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP Enum(BOOL fForward, IEnumMoniker **ppenumMoniker) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP IsEqual(IMoniker *pmkOtherMoniker) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP Hash(DWORD *pdwHash) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP IsRunning(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, IMoniker *pmkNewlyRunning) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP GetTimeOfLastChange(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, FILETIME *pFileTime) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP Inverse(IMoniker **ppmk) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP CommonPrefixWith(IMoniker *pmkOther, IMoniker **ppmkPrefix) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP RelativePathTo(IMoniker *pmkOther, IMoniker **ppmkRelPath) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP ParseDisplayName(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, LPOLESTR pszDisplayName, ULONG *pchEaten, IMoniker **ppmkOut) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP IsSystemMoniker(DWORD *pdwMksys) { return E_NOTIMPL; }

                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                // IPersistStream
                //--------------------------------------------------------------

                STDMETHODIMP IsDirty() { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP Load(IStream *pStm) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP Save(IStream *pStm, BOOL fClearDirty) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
                STDMETHODIMP GetSizeMax(ULARGE_INTEGER *pcbSize) { return E_NOTIMPL; }

                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                // IPersist
                //--------------------------------------------------------------

                STDMETHODIMP GetClassID(CLSID *pClassID) { return E_NOTIMPL; }
    };

 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // IUnknown::QueryInterface
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 STDMETHODIMP TMoniker::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
 {
 if (!ppv) return E_POINTER;
 
 if      (IID_IUnknown       == riid)    *ppv = (IUnknown *)      this;
 else if (IID_IMoniker       == riid)    *ppv = (IMoniker *)      this;
 else if (IID_IPersistStream == riid)    *ppv = (IPersistStream *)this;
 else if (IID_IPersist       == riid)    *ppv = (IPersist *)      this;
 else
    {
    *ppv = NULL;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
 
 // AddRef It
 ((IUnknown*)*ppv)->AddRef();
 
 return S_OK;
 }
 
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // IUnknown::AddRef
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) TMoniker::AddRef()
 {
 return ::InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
 }
 
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // IUnknown::Release
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) TMoniker::Release()
 {
 LONG cRef = ::InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
 if (0 == cRef) delete this;
 return cRef;
 }
```

Load the content:

```cpp
TMoniker* pMnk = new TMoniker("about:blank", "file://c:\\temp\\file.html");

LPBC pbc=0;

DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2 = WB->Document;
if (diDoc2)
    {
    DelphiInterface<IPersistMoniker> diPM;
    if (SUCCEEDED(diDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistMoniker, (void**)&diPM)))
        {
        if (SUCCEEDED(CreateBindCtx(0, &pbc)))
            {
            // !!! returns `E_INVALIDARG` here !!!
            if (SUCCEEDED(diPM->Load(TRUE, pmk, pbc, STGM_READWRITE)))
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

if (pbc) pbc->Release();

pMnk->Release();
```

Comment: What a dumb error, I used `ppszDisplayName = this->baseUrl;` instead of `*ppszDisplayName = this->baseUrl;` !!

Comment: Even with that *fix*, you still have an error, because you are not returning a *copy* of the `BSTR` that `baseUrl` holds. The caller is going to free the returned string, so you don't want it freeing the `baseUrl`'s inner `BSTR` directly, which is what you are returning now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few issues with your code:

- the `ppszDisplayName` parameter of `GetDisplayName()` is an `[out]` parameter. It receives the address of a caller-provided `OLESTR*` pointer, and you are expected to set that pointer to an OLE string that is allocated with `IMalloc::Alloc()` or equivalent.  But you are not doing that.  In fact, you are not returning *any* string back to the caller at all, because you are not *dereferencing* the `ppszDisplayName` parameter so you can access the pointer it is pointing at to assign a value to it.

  You can change `baseUrl` from `OleVariant` to `WideString`, and then use `WideString::Copy()` (which uses `SysAllocStringLen()`, which is compatible with `IMalloc`) to return an allocated copy of `baseUrl` to the caller:

```cpp
private: WideString baseUrl;

STDMETHODIMP GetDisplayName(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, LPOLESTR *ppszDisplayName)
{
    //Application->MessageBox(L"GetDisplayName", L"Info", MB_OK); // Check if method is called
    if (!ppszDisplayName) return E_POINTER;
    *ppszDisplayName = baseUrl.Copy();
    return S_OK;
}
```

- the `ppvObj` parameter of `BindToStorage()` is likewise also an `[out]` parameter, but you are not *dereferencing* the passed pointer to return something back to the caller.

  You were on the right track using `TStreamAdapter`, though, you just need to finish it:

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP BindToStorage(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, REFIID riid, void **ppvObj)
{
    //Application->MessageBox(L"BindToStorage", L"Info", MB_OK); // Check if method is called

    if (!ppvObj) return E_POINTER;
    *ppvObj = NULL;

    if (!IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IStream)) return E_NOINTERFACE;

    //Application->MessageBox(L"IMoniker::BindToStorage", L"Info", MB_OK);
    DelphiInterface<IStream> sa(*(new TStreamAdapter(memStream.get(), soReference)));
    *ppvObj = (IStream*)sa;
    /* or simply:
    *ppvObj = (IStream*) *(new TStreamAdapter(memStream.get(), soReference));
    */
    sa->AddRef(); // <-- don't forget this, whether you use DelphiInterface or not!

    return S_OK;
}
```

However, I would actually suggest changing `memStream` from `TMemoryStream` to `IStream` so it is not possible for any `IStream` given out by `BindToStorage()` to outlive the HTML data it is referring to:

```cpp
#include <System.StrUtils.hpp>
#include <memory>

private: DelphiInterface<IStream> diStrm;

TMoniker(const UnicodeString& fBaseUrl, const UnicodeString& fContent)
{
    ...

    UnicodeString path = fContent;
    if (StartsText(L"file://", fContent))
        path.Delete(1, 7);

    std::auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> memStream(new TMemoryStream); // or std::unique_ptr in C++11 and later...
    memStream->LoadFromFile(fContent);
    memStream->Position = 0;

    diStrm = *(new TStreamAdapter(memStream.get(), soOwned));
    memStream.release();
}

...

STDMETHODIMP BindToStorage(IBindCtx *pbc, IMoniker *pmkToLeft, REFIID riid, void **ppvObj)
{
    return diStrm->QueryInterface(riid, ppvObj);
}
```

- though this is optional, I highly suggest you wrap the `pMnk` and `pbc` variables in `DelphiInterface` or other smart COM pointer, let it handle calling `Release()` for you.  You can also use `OleCheck()` to simplify your error handling:

```cpp
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc2 = WB->Document;
if (diDoc2)
{
    DelphiInterface<IPersistMoniker> diPM;
    OleCheck(diDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistMoniker, (void**)&diPM));
    // or: OleCheck(diDoc2->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&diPM)));

    DelphiInterface<IBindCtx> diBC;
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, &diBC));

    // set m_cRef to 0 in the TMoniker constructor, not 1...
    DelphiInterface<IMoniker> diMnk(new TMoniker(L"about:blank", L"file://c:\\temp\\file.html"));

    OleCheck(diPM->Load(TRUE, diMnk, diBC, STGM_READ));
}
```